# Modeling magnetic field of permanent magnet: Where to start?

Tags: magnetism, finite-element-analysis

I would like to model magnetic field of a permanent magnet like this one [magnet](https://www.magnet4less.com/diametrically-magnetized-n50-neodymium-magnet-1-4-in-x-1-2-in-cylinder?gclid=Cj0KCQjwt-6LBhDlARIsAIPRQcLFxN6WzdzDA1_n9qiQGflnW0oRf_lLmS-oh1HBQgYHBysKOyR-sdQaAmMaEALw_wcB) . Ideally, I would like to do it python or any other language. I would like to start with some simple geometry and some properties of the material and end up with vector field. I am planning to move this vector field around and observe generated voltage. So far I found a couple of python libraries and [FEMM](https://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) with Python API. FEMM looks the most promising, but really hard to understand. Are there any tutorials for FEMM? Also what does the modelling process consists off? I see that finite element method is used, but I am not clear why are we trying to solve certain equations numerically? Do we represent permanent magnet as coil and the using Maxwell equation trying to figure out the vector field? What if our permanent magnet shape is far from simple coil geometry? I am willing to start with something simple like finite difference. Too many questions, not sure where to start.

Comment: There are lot of questions within the post. I know there can be a lot of questions when you are just starting out with something, but it may help to narrow it down to what you consider the most important of these questions and ask the others if the initial question doesn't clear things up. I'm not an expert in finite element methods and it seems this question has had a tough time garnering attention here. It may be worth trying it this question on [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-element), which has a lot of finite element questions.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.